# Is declaring strict in PHP safe to use in combination with frameworks like Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am thinking of getting rid of all the automatic type conversions in PHP. But when I apply declare(strict_types=1) I am afraid this might give a collision with my framework Laravel. So my question is: Is it still safe to use declare(strict_types=1) in all my PHP files even though Laravel does not declare all its PHP files strict?

Comment: You mean _safe_, right? And strict mode will work only for file that you declare it in, so it won't collide with Laravel files.

Comment: For instance I declare a function with input string. The input is coming from Laravel and it turns out it could either be false or a string. Then I will have a bug in my code when Laravel suddenly gives me false instead of a string. (save is safe now :) )

Comment: I now see that any bug rising from declaring a function with type hinting and declaring strict_types will arise locally and not just in production. So it is a good thing to deal with this kind of bug right away.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `declare(strict_types=1)` will affect only file with function declaration, not definition. For example:

#### foo.php

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    function parseInt(int $value) {}
```

#### bar.php

```
<?php
    require 'foo.php';
    parseInt('123');
```

If you execute **bar.php** - it won't throw error. If you would use `parseInt('123')` inside **foo.php** and execute that file, then it would throw an error.

So as long as you won't touch Laravel source code, nothing bad will happen.